# Do there exist countinuously differentiable functions $f,g$ such that $f(x)g(x) = x$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Do there exist continuously differentiable functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and for every $x {\in} \mathbb{R}, \,f(x)g(x) = x$ ?

My solution:

No. Since $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions and $f(x)g(x) = x$, we have $f'(0)g(0) + f(0)g'(0)= 1$, which is not possible if  $f(0) = g(0) = 0$.

---

Why does the exercise specify that $f$ and $g$ must be CONTINUOUSLY differentiable? It seems weird to add that if we don't need it; did I miss something?

Comment: Your reasoning looks good to me, I don't see why would we need continuity of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Continuity ensures the derivatives don't blow up at the origin, making the proof simpler. Presumably this exercise isn't intended to handle functions with weird oscillatory behavior near the origin.

Comment: Would my solution be wrong if derivatives of $f$ and $g$ weren't continuous?

Comment: @eyeballfrog continuity does not make the proof simpler. The OP did not use it and their proof couldn't be simpler.

Comment: The product rule holds at any point where $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable, without any other conditions. $f, g$ need to both be differentiable at $0$ for this proof to work. But elsewhere, there is no need for them to even be continuous, much less differentiable, or continuously differentiable.